# How to get extended interface using Reflection class in PHP

Tags: php, reflection, php-5.3

I have a class that implements an interface, and that interface extends another interface.  The setting is like that:

```
interface A{
}

interface B extends A {
}

class C implements B {
}


$obj = new C();
```

I want to know which interfaces the object $obj implements.  I tried to create a ReflectionClass object and then calling the getInterfaces method, but it only returns me the interface B:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
print_r($reflection->getInterfaces());
```

I also tried to create a ReflectionClass object using the interface name, but when I call the getInterfaces() method, it returns an empty array.

Does any of you guys know how to get an interface name that extends a given interface?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Steve

Comment: Can not reproduce, [`ReflectionClass::getInterfaces()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getinterfaces.php) should give you what you are looking for. Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PoDCHm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Reflection for this. You can simply use

- [`class_implements`](http://php.net/class_implements) — Return the interfaces which are implemented by the given class

Example for your code snippet:

```
var_dump(class_implements($obj));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["B"]=>
  string(1) "B"
  ["A"]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
```

Comment: @Steve 5.2.14, 5.3.3, 5.3.6 and 5.4RC5

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
interface A {}
interface B extends A {}
class C implements B {}
$obj = new C();

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($reflection->getInterfaces());
echo "</pre>";
```

Your example outputs this for me (IDE debugger is running on PHP 5.2.17):

```
Array
(
    [B] => ReflectionClass Object
        (
            [name] => B
        )

    [A] => ReflectionClass Object
        (
            [name] => A
        )

)
```

Comment: Shown above - PHP 5.2.17. Gordon is right though. Reflection is not needed for this.

Comment: I use PHP version 5.3.6 and the results are the ones shown above.  Thx anyway, Ill do more testing.